# orderBy() a relationship without using joins

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Up until now, I've been doing this to order by a model's relationship:

```
$users = User::leftJoin('user_stats', 'users.id', '=', 'user_stats.user_id')
    ->orderBy('user_stats.num_followers')
    ->get();
```

Here's the `User` model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function stats()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\UserStat');
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to `orderBy` a model's relationship without having to use any joins? I'm using Laravel 5.2.

Comment: Could you show us the tables structure?

Comment: Could you please be bit more specific with your question? What do you mean by *better way*? What do you not like about the way you're currently doing it? Why do you want to avoid the join? Performance?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Collection instead:

```
$users = User::with('stats')->get()->sortBy(function($user, $key) {
    return $user['stats']['num_followers'];
})->values()->all();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-sortby

Answer (score 0):

As long as the column you want to order by is on a different table (eg. on a related model), you'll have to join that table in.

**The Collection sort:**
The proposal by crabbly does not save you the join. It only sorts the collection manually in php, after the data has been fetched using a join.

*Edit:* In fact, the `with('stats')` generates no join, but instead a separate `SELECT * FROM user_stats WHERE ID IN (x, y, z, …)`. So well, it actually saves you a join.

**Maintain a copy:**
A way of truly saving the join would be to have a copy of `num_followers` directly in the users table. Or maybe store it only there, so you don't have to keep the values in sync.